# combine text files with same name in one file

Tags: java, batch-file, text, merge

I have around 1000 text files with same name but different content. I want to merge them according to their names.
Eg.

```
Company1.txt ,Company1.txt,Company1.txt 

Company2.txt, Company2.txt

Company3.txt, Company3.txt, Company3.txt, Company3.txt
```

All the instances of Company1 contain different content. I want to merge all the Company1.txt into one single file and want to repeat the same for Company2.txt, Company3.txt and so on.

How should I do?

```
Company1.txt is present in D:\TextFiles\Part1
Company1.txt is present in D:\TextFiles\Part2
Company1.txt is present in D:\TextFiles\Part3
```

Same is the case for the other text files.

Comment: I dont know how to approach the solution.

Comment: how is Java and batch related to each other? And you can't have files with the same name in the same folder, but you haven't shown what the folder structure looks like

Comment: You should at least show what the folder structure looks like if you want help.

Comment: added the folder structure

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúcSorry for the inconvenience. added the structure.batch and java not related. Was taking opinions whether to go by java programming or batch file processing.

Comment: Who cares what the folder structure looks like? It's not like OP tried anything and they're obviously in different folders.
@Rai read each file, use StringBuilder and append each file content then write to file. Google will tell you how to do each of these things, i'm sure you can connect the dots yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a temp folder: `mergeTestFiles`, then three sub folder: `part1,part2,part3`
Then in each folder I created a: Doc1.txt file:

```
The Doc1.txt in the part1 folder has the line: "part 1"
The Doc1.txt in the part2 folder has the line: "part 2"
The Doc1.txt in the part3 folder has the line: "part 3"
```

i.e.:
mergeTestFiles\part1\Doc1.txt

**In power shell - here is the file structure.**

PS C:\temp\mergeTestFiles> ls -Recurse

```
Directory: C:\temp\mergeTestFiles
```

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        16/01/2018     16:26            part1
d----        16/01/2018     16:26            part2
d----        16/01/2018     16:26            part3

```
Directory: C:\temp\mergeTestFiles\part1
```

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        16/01/2018     16:27         18 Doc1.txt

```
Directory: C:\temp\mergeTestFiles\part2
```

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        16/01/2018     16:27         18 Doc1.txt

```
Directory: C:\temp\mergeTestFiles\part3
```

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        16/01/2018     16:27         18 Doc1.txt

In power shell I can run:

```
Get-Content .\part*\Doc1.txt
part 1
part 2
part 3
```

Which displays all the contents merged together (notice the * in the path)

Hope this helps

Well if there is a complete set of files, on one of your folders, you could use their filenames to drive it like this.

Note: the sub folder part1, has an instance of all the files so we will use this to get the names, and drive the merge.

like this:
   Foreach($file in ls part1) { Get-Content .\part*\$file }

I've added Doc2.txt to part1 subfolder.

```
PS C:\temp\mergeTestFiles> Foreach($file in ls part1) { Get-Content .\part*\$file }
part 1
part 2
part 3
file Doc2.txt in part1 subfolder
```

And if your file names are all the same format

i.e. *Company{number}.txt*

- like in your question you could use a range like this:

  Foreach($file in 1..10) { Get-Content .\part*\Doc$file.txt }

Which would also ensure the ordering of the files in the merge

Comment: Thank you so much. However, since I have files with multiple names do I need to write individually for all the files the code? Apart from Doc1.txt as you have shown I have other files like Doc2.txt, Doc3.txt ....Doc1000.txt in the folders Part1, Part2 and Part3